# Building query params which append to URL in a browser

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, url

I was looking for a similar JavaScript method for [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) but did not find but create my own and here I am a bit confused to decide the right approach.

Here is the problem. I have an object of params and need to create query string to append with URL with help of [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
const params = {
    "name": ["alpha &", "beta"],
    "id": ["one", "&two=2"],
    "from": 1533735971000,
    "to": 1533822371147,
    "status": true
};
```

Now there are two approaches when there is an array of strings are there. I name them `pre-encode` and `post-encode` for now.

## `pre-encode`

Apply `encodeURIComponent` to individual items and then join all items.

```js
const params = {
  "name": ["alpha &", "beta"],
  "id": ["one", "&two=2"],
  "from": 1533735971000,
  "to": 1533822371147,
  "status": true
};

const output = Object.entries(params).map((pair) => {
  const [key, val] = pair;
  if (val instanceof Array && val.length > 0) {
    let pre_encode = val.map(encodeURIComponent).join(',');
    console.log({pre_encode});
    const pre_qs = `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${pre_encode}`;
    console.log({pre_qs})
    return pre_qs;
  } else {
    return pair.map(encodeURIComponent).join('=');
  }

}).join('&');


console.log({output});
```

#### Output

> "name=alpha%20%26,beta&id=one,%26two%3D2&from=1533735971000&to=1533822371147&status=true"

---

## `post-encode`

First, join all items then apply `encodeURIComponent`.

```js
const params = {
  "name": ["alpha &", "beta"],
  "id": ["one", "&two=2"],
  "from": 1533735971000,
  "to": 1533822371147,
  "status": true
};

const output = Object.entries(params).map((pair) => {
  const [key, val] = pair;
  if (val instanceof Array && val.length > 0) {
    let post_encode = encodeURIComponent(val.join(','));
    console.log({post_encode});
    const post_qs = `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${post_encode}`;
    console.log({post_qs})
    return post_qs;
  } else {
    return pair.map(encodeURIComponent).join('=');
  }

}).join('&');


console.log({output});
```

#### Output

> "name=alpha%20%26%2Cbeta&id=one%2C%26two%3D2&from=1533735971000&to=1533822371147&status=true"

Which approach is the more efficient and right and how to handle null and undefined values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Your main question

I have trouble understanding it, because:

- **minor reason**:
  (unless I'm missing something obvious) whatever way you encode the array parts, the resulting query string is quite valid in both cases;
  so the only possible criterion for choosing a method rather than the other one would be to find which one is faster... and this sounds a bit overkill!
- **major reason**:
  you initially referred to the PHP `http_build_query()` function, so I'd expect you work the same, i.e. for a given `key: [val_1, val_2]`:

  - you're currently returning `key=val_1,val_2`
  - while it should be `key=val_1&key=val_2`

To match the latter case, I'd suggest something like this:

```
const output = Object.entries(params).map(
  (pair) => {
    let [key, val] = pair;
    // normalize val to always an array
    val = (val instanceof Array) ? val : [val];
    // encode key only once
    key = encodeURIComponent(key);
    // then make a different query string for each val member
    return val.map(
      (member) => `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(member)}`
    ).join('&');
  }
).join('&');
```

## Your complementary question

To implement null or undefined, first you have to decide how they must be managed: they might be simply omitted, or included with no value (its often useful to have query params where only its presence/absence is meaningful for the underlying application).

Anyway you may simply add any of these capabilities; instead of

```
    return val.map(
      (member) => `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(member)}`
    ).join('&');
```

you can include null/undefined params simply with:

```
return val.map(
  (member) => (member ? `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(member)}` : `${key}`)
).join('&');
```

*(NOTE: it's up to you to enhance this with more precise tests if desired, in order to keep `0` as `key=0`, or `''` as `key=`)*

or you can omit them with a slightly different method:

```
return val.reduce(
  (result, member) => {
    if (member) {
      result.push(`${key}=${encodeURIComponent(member)}`);
    }
    return result;
  },
  []
).join('&');
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I was using `.filter` to remove `null` and undefined key and value prior to encoding. additionally using I need query in `key=val_1,val_2` format and I think that is right way instead of adding each key and value separately. isn't it. does server treat these both `key=val1&key=val2` ,  `key=val1,val2` as same or it depends on mechanism how they read the query params in my case BE is java?

Comment: @pro.mean I can't say anything really pertinent about java. But you referred to PHP, and you can check that it's how it works. Subsequently I tend to think that it'd be the same with java, since browsers are necessarily agnostic with regard to server languages. In PHP, a query string like `key=val1&key=val2` is "rendered" inside of the `$_GET`array as a member like `'key' => ['val1', 'val2']`.

Comment: `if (member)`  does not prevent `null` value

Comment: @pro.mean I must insist: `if (member)` prevents `null`, `undefined`, `0`, and `''` (it's why I added a comment about the two latters). Tested!